# Duplicate data on html table when I refresh the page

Tags: php, html, mysql, duplicates, html-table

I am selecting some data from db and I am trying to display them on a html table.
The problem is that when i refresh the page I get all the data duplicated on my html table. I have been trying to google/fix this issue but no results for three days now.

```
 <?php
    //select and display all post on a table.
    $query="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts order by post_id";
    $results=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

$data[] = array_unique($row); 
echo "<tr>";
foreach($data as $result)
{
    foreach($result as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($key=="post_content"){
            continue;
        } if($key=="post_img"){
            $value="<img width='100px' src='../imgs/$value' class='img-responsive'>";
        }
        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
    }
  echo "</tr>";

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code looks a bit wired. Why do you make an `array_unique` on the result set? If you make a distinct you can iterate directly through your results.

Comment: I used array_unique since i wanted to make sure that I am not getting those duplicate data from the array itself, but even with that function used I still keep getting duplicates when i refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the `while` loop runs, this:

```
$data[] = array_unique($row);
```

creates a new array and adds the row to it (I don't think `array_unique` is really accomplishing anything).

With each subsequent iteration of your `while` loop, you add another row to `$data`. Then, you loop over `$data` with:

```
foreach($data as $result) {
```

This is what's causing the duplication. `$data` incrementally gets every row from `$results`, and you loop over it repeatedly. By the end of your `while` loop, `$data` contains your entire result set.

Removing the extra loop should eliminate this problem.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "post_content") {
            continue;
        }
        if ($key == "post_img") {
            $value = "<img width='100px' src='../imgs/$value' class='img-responsive'>";
        }
        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: that worked, despite the reason that I have first tried to iterate through the row array but for some reasons I was getting only numbers in order from 0, that made me think that i probably need to iterate twice in order to get the the data inside the array. Now its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `array_unique` is not a good idea and isn't working. I don't know your entries but i think it's better to group that field you need only once.

```
<?php
//select and display all post on a table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id GROUP BY xxxxx";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    if ($key == "post_content") {
        continue;
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    if ($key == "post_img") {
        echo "<td><img width='100px' src='../imgs/{$row['value']}' class='img-responsive'></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Then you shouldn't have doublicate values.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're adding to `$data` inside the outer `while`, and then iterating over `$data` inside the while.

Here's some pseudocode attempting to show what I mean:

```
while(new row) {
    $data[] = $row; // adding row to data
    foreach($data as $result) {
        // iterate over all rows in data, ever
    }
}
```

For the first db result, $data is empty.  You add to it, display, move on.  Second db result, $data still has the first result in it.. you add the second result, then iterate over it displaying both the first result (again) and the second result.

Third time through, data has results 1 and 2 and 3 is added.. then 1, 2, and 3 are *all* displayed.